# extracting data from different files with a loop

Tags: python, text

I want to extract some data from a text file (txtU2), and this is done in a loop because of the change of the folder in which my text file exist!
I tried three way of writing this code, but all of them are incorrect:

```
# 1) with open("D:/Prozhey/%d'%(jj+1)/txtU2.txt", "rb") as f: # Open file in read-binary mode

# 2) with open("D:/Prozheye_Avval/JOB/%d"%(jj+1) + "/txtU2.txt", "rb") as f: # Open file in read-binary mode

# 3)
with open('D:/Prozheye_Avval/JOB/%d'%(jj+1) + '/txtU2.txt', "rb") as f: # Open file in read-binary mode
    lines = f.readlines() # Load all lines
x2 = []
U2 = []
```

Could anyone please tell me the correct one?

Comment: Definitely not the first one, and there's absolutely no difference between the other two. Single/double quotations doesn't matter in Python

Comment: What is jj and where exactly is your file, and where's your loop?

Comment: What is your error code?